# How to link against a shared library without inclusion in final package?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, shared-libraries

I have been working with a project that needs to link against two shared libraries from other applications, without actually including them in the final package. I was using Android Studio with a common way of executing an external `ndk-build` but I am now using the experimental gradle NDK support.

From what I understand from the information [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-NDK-Dependencies), using the jniLibs source set will package the binary with the final application, which is not what I want. I would like to link against the libraries during compile time, and expect that my own module is loaded in an environment where they are available.

My old workaround was to add the line: `TARGET_NO_UNDEFINED_LDFLAGS :=` within the Android.mk, but I'm not aware of any way to something equivalent with the new NDK support.

Currently, I am including the `jni` directory which contains the libraries alongside my source by adding `-L"<directory>"` to `ldFlags`, and linking against them as I would with a system library, as below (currently, I am only building for ARMv7):

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "ropecraftpe"
    ldLibs.addAll(['log', 'name of one library', 'name of other library'])
    ldFlags.add('-L"' + file('src/main/jni').absolutePath + '"')

    cppFlags.add('-std=c++11')
    stl = 'gnustl_shared'
    abiFilters.addAll(['armeabi-v7a'])
}
```

This works for the most part - oddly enough, the linker does not complain about calls to static functions or globals, but *does* complain when attempting to use a constructor defined in one of the libraries: `Error:(12) undefined reference to 'ClassName::ClassName(std::string const&, etc.)'`. This class is defined in a header file included from my own C++ code, and the constructor is definitely present in the linked `.so`.

How does one go about linking this project successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I have made a workaround; my solution was to add the libraries that I wished to link against to the NDK's system library directory.

This is located under `ANDROID_NDK/platforms/android-XX/arch-XX/usr/lib/`. This appears to work fine, as I wanted the libraries to be treated in the same way as system libraries (not included as prebuilts, but still linked against).

As an addition, one can place the header files under the `include` directory there.